# tengo un shared preferences con el siguiente error:

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, sharedpreferences

gracias por llegar aqui, sucede que tengo en un fragmento un shared preferences para poner un nombre con un edit text y pasar este a otro fragmento, creo que hasta aqui no hay problema pero lo que sucede es que cuando hago el intent por medio de mi boton  la app se cierra y cuando la corro debuggeada el problema dice ser el siguiente:

**logcat del debug**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.overworld.protbox, PID: 15973
java.lang.IllegalStateException: tv_text must not be null
    at com.overworld.protbox.NameFragment.loadData(NameFragment.kt:69)
    at com.overworld.protbox.NameFragment.onCreateView(NameFragment.kt:40)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8192)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
```

**nameFragment**

```
class NameFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val callba = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true){
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nameFragment_to_homeFragment)
        }
    }

    requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(callba)

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_name, container, false)
    //sharedpreferences
    loadData()

    bt_button.setOnClickListener {
        saveData()
    }

    view.bt_button.setOnClickListener { Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_nameFragment_to_homeFragment) }

    return view
}

//shared preferences
private fun saveData(){

    val insertedText = et_text.toString()
    tv_text.text = insertedText

    val sharedPreferences = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    editor.apply {
        putString("STRING_KEY", insertedText)
    }.apply()

}

private fun loadData(){
    val sharedPreferences = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val savedString = sharedPreferences.getString("STRING_KEY", null)

    tv_text.text = savedString
}
```

}

**al parecer el error esta en el tv_text en el load y este dice que no deberia ser null, podrian ayudarme porfavor a encontrar una solucion?**

Comment: no veo que en el onCreate estés inicializando: tv_text, por eso en el error te dice que no debe ser null, debés iniciarlo para que te deje de fallar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a probar